# Unexpected beahviour when replacing object properties

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm using mocha to run tests against newly written class and need to build a number of `Event`'s to make a comparison. I've planned to use object stubs and replace them with actual instances of `Event` class, which have an async constructor due to DB connection usage. So I'm using *recursive* calls to process stubs in sequence.
And here is the problem: all my stub objects replaced with latest instance and I have no idea why. Please explain me where I am wrong.

Event.coffee:

```
class Event
    start = 0
    duration = 0
    title = ""
    atype = {}

    constructor: (_start, _duration, _title, _atype, cb) ->
        start = _start
        duration = _duration
        title = _title

        evt = @
        ActivityType.find( {} =
            where: {} =
                title: _atype
        ).success( (res) ->
            atype = res

            cb? evt
        ).error( () ->
            throw new Error "unable to assign atype '#{_atype}'"
        )
# ...
```

Event.test.coffee:

```
# ...
suite "getEventAt", () ->
    events =
        FREE: {} =
            start: 0
            duration: Day.MINUTES_PER_DAY
            title: "Free time"
            type: "FREE"
        REST: {} =
            start: 10
            duration: 30
            title: "rest"
            type: "_REST"
        FITNESS: {} =
            start: 30
            duration: 30
            title: "fitness"
            type: "_FITNESS"
        WORK: {} =
            start: 20
            duration: 30
            title: "work"
            type: "_WORK"

    suiteSetup (done) ->
        buildEvent = (ki) ->
            ks = Object.keys events
            ( (k) ->
                v = events[k]
                new Event v.start, v.duration, v.title, v.type, (e) ->
                    events[k] = e
                    if k == ks[ks.length-1]
                        return done?()
                    return buildEvent(ki+1)
            )(ks[ki])
        buildEvent(0)
# ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start duration title and atype are class variables, thus overwritten each time you create a new Event

```
class Event

    constructor: (_start, _duration, _title, _atype, cb) ->
        @start = _start
        @duration = _duration
        @title = _title

        evt = @
        ActivityType.find( {} =
            where: {} =
                title: _atype
        ).success( (res) =>
            @atype = res

            cb? evt
        ).error( () ->
            throw new Error "unable to assign atype '#{_atype}'"
        )
```

Please, note the flat-arrow at success callback (see: http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow for further details)